# Spatie's Activity Log not working on second external database connection

Tags: laravel, logging

The logging is not working for the external database connection models, but it is for the default database connection.

I am working with two databases.

For a `User.php` model that works with the dafult connection:

```php
use Spatie\Activitylog\LogOptions;
use Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\LogsActivity;

class User
{
    use LogsActivity;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'email_verified_at',
    ];

    /**
     * Spatie's activity log settings.
     * @return LogOptions
     */
    public function getActivitylogOptions(): LogOptions
    {
        return LogOptions::defaults()->logFillable();
    }
```

The logging is working fine.

**However**, with another model that connects to another database:

```php
class Event extends Model
{
    use LogsActivity;

    /**
     * External DB connection
     * @var string
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connection = config('database.connections.external');
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [ ... ]

    /**
     * Spatie's activity log settings.
     * @return LogOptions
     */
    public function getActivitylogOptions(): LogOptions
    {
        return LogOptions::defaults()->logFillable();
    }
```

The logging is not working at all.

Why is this happenig? Any workaround to fix this?

Comment: you are overriding the constructor of the model and not calling the parent constructor (which has things to do, like initializing traits, and takes an array of arguments), btw

Comment: How do you call the parent constructor? After that, how do I merge it with my custom constructor?